# Get "Invalid characters in string" error when pass Byte array from C# to C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c++-cli

I need to invoke some native method in C# to process a Byte array. So, I wrote some C++/CLI code to wrap the native code.

But When I pass the Byte array from C# to the C++/CLI code, I got "Invalid Characters in string" error.

I don't have much experience about interop between managed code and native code.

Could anyone can help me to figure out the reason.

The code looks like below snippet:

C++/CLI code:

```
volid CppCliClass::HandleArray(array<System::Byte>^ byteArray)
{
    pin_ptr<System::Byte> p = &byteArray[0];

    // Some Other logic
}
```

C# code:

```
        var cppInstance = new CppCliClass();
        Byte[] byteArr = new Byte[] { 227, 221 };
        cppInstance.HandleArray(byteArr);
```

The error screen shot:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

["Invalid characters in string" in the **Locals**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEwhd.png)

Comment: I can see no error. What do you expect? You pass Bytes 227 and 221 and I can see the same values in array in the C++/CLI function.

Comment: I am confused why the bytes are interpreted as some non-English characters, you can see in the screen shot. I already checked the project configuration, the char-set is Unicode.  Thanks! @xMRi

Comment: `Byte` is an alias for `unsigned char` in C++/CLI, so it is not entirely bizarre that the debugger will try to interpret the pointer content as characters.  That the C language did not have a dedicated type for bytes was a design decision that has haunted us forever.  The debugger displays the content using your computer's system locale setting, we don't know what it might be.  No obvious candidates, but clearly it doesn't like character code 227.  The simple workaround is to look at `byteArray` instead of `p`.

Comment: I suspect you might be using VS2017.  Currently in beta, be sure to file a bug report at connect.microsoft.com.  And be sure to use the correct debugger, C++/CLI is no longer compatible with later managed debugging engines.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.

Comment: I am using VS2015. It's proved the invalid characters error message doesn't have effect to the process result.  Thanks for your reply. @HansPassant